# How can I use XString to count characters in a string with the "wrong" catcode?

Tags: tikz-pgf, catcodes, xstring

I created a Ti*k*Z coordinate system to solve a positioning problem I had. The code is presented below. However, the code doesn't work; if you run it, you will get the

> Too many .'s

error message even though there are, in fact, the correct number of dots in each coordinate in the test tikzpicture. Careful investigation reveals that the macro `\sidecs@numberofats` is not being populated with the correct value: it always ends up being zero.

Since I have used `\makeatletter` before defining the coordinate system code, but "@" is an "other" character in the `tikzpicture` where the coordinates appear, my assumption is that this is a catcode issue. This supposition is backed up by the fact that if you change `@` to `:` everywhere it appears (apart from in macro names, obviously), the document compiles successfully and has the expected appearance.

How can I get XString to count the `@` characters? Most XString macros have a starred version that (as the manual explains) disregards catcodes, but for whatever reason, `\StrCount` does not.

(I wanted to use the built-in PGF parsing library to do this rather than XString, but it isn't full-featured enough. Specifically, it appears that you can't provide a rule that works for "any character not amongst those separately specified", and since I want to accept node names - which might contain almost any character at all - this is no good.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz, xstring}

\makeatletter
    \def\sidecs@expandtotop{top}
    \def\sidecs@expandtobottom{bottom}
    \def\sidecs@expandtoleft{left}
    \def\sidecs@expandtoright{right}

    \def\sidecs@trimspacesleft#1{%
        \IfBeginWith{#1}%
                    { }%
                    {\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[#1]\sidecs@trimspacesleft{#1}}%
                    {}%
    }
    \def\sidecs@trimspacesright#1{%
        \IfEndWith{#1}%
                  { }%
                  {\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[#1]\sidecs@trimspacesright{#1}}%
                  {}%
    }

    \tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{side}{
        \begingroup
            \fullexpandarg
            \edef\sidecs@expandedarg{#1}
            \StrCount{\sidecs@expandedarg}{@}[\sidecs@numberofats]
            \if\sidecs@numberofats0
                \let\sidecs@partbeforeat\sidecs@expandedarg
                \def\sidecs@pos{0.5}
                \def\sidecs@posreversed{0.5}
            \else\if\sidecs@numberofats1
                \StrCut{\sidecs@expandedarg}{@}{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{\sidecs@pos}
                \pgfmathsubtract{1}{\sidecs@pos}
                \let\sidecs@posreversed\pgfmathresult
            \else
                \errmessage{Too many @'s in side cs coordinate}
            \fi\fi
            \StrCount{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{.}[\sidecs@numberofdots]
            \if\sidecs@numberofdots0
                \errmessage{Not enough .'s in side cs coordinate}
            \else\if\sidecs@numberofdots1
            \else
                \errmessage{Too many .'s in side cs coordinate}
            \fi\fi
            \StrCut{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{.}{\sidecs@node}{\sidecs@side}
            \sidecs@trimspacesleft{\sidecs@node}
            \sidecs@trimspacesright{\sidecs@node}
            \sidecs@trimspacesleft{\sidecs@side}
            \sidecs@trimspacesright{\sidecs@side}
            \ifx\sidecs@side\sidecs@expandtotop
                \def\sidecs@anchorone{north west}
                \def\sidecs@anchortwo{north east}
            \else\ifx\sidecs@side\sidecs@expandtobottom
                \def\sidecs@anchorone{south west}
                \def\sidecs@anchortwo{south east}
            \else\ifx\sidecs@side\sidecs@expandtoleft
                \def\sidecs@anchorone{north west}
                \def\sidecs@anchortwo{south west}
            \else\ifx\sidecs@side\sidecs@expandtoright
                \def\sidecs@anchorone{north east}
                \def\sidecs@anchortwo{south east}
            \else
                \errmessage{Unknown side}
            \fi\fi\fi\fi
            \pgfpointadd%
                {\pgfpointscale{\sidecs@posreversed}%
                               {\pgfpointanchor{\sidecs@node}{\sidecs@anchorone}}}%
                {\pgfpointscale{\sidecs@pos}%
                               {\pgfpointanchor{\sidecs@node}{\sidecs@anchortwo}}}
            \global\pgf@x=\pgf@x
            \global\pgf@y=\pgf@y
        \endgroup
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[x = 35mm, y = 3mm, every node/.style = draw]
            \node (x) at (0,  0) {XXXXXXXXXX};

            \node (a) at (1,  7) {AAAAAAAAAA};
            \node (b) at (1,  5) {BBBBBBBBBB};
            \node (c) at (1,  3) {CCCCCCCCCC};
            \node (d) at (1,  1) {DDDDDDDDDD};
            \node (e) at (1, -1) {EEEEEEEEEE};
            \node (f) at (1, -3) {FFFFFFFFFF};
            \node (g) at (1, -5) {GGGGGGGGGG};
            \node (h) at (1, -7) {HHHHHHHHHH};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[->,
                      tl/.style = {out = 90, in = 180},
                      bl/.style = {out = 270, in = 180}]
            \draw [tl] (side cs: x.top    @ 0.5) to (side cs: a.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [tl] (side cs: x.top    @ 0.6) to (side cs: b.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [tl] (side cs: x.top    @ 0.7) to (side cs: c.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [tl] (side cs: x.top    @ 0.8) to (side cs: d.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [bl] (side cs: x.bottom @ 0.8) to (side cs: e.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [bl] (side cs: x.bottom @ 0.7) to (side cs: f.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [bl] (side cs: x.bottom @ 0.6) to (side cs: g.left @ 0.5);
            \draw [bl] (side cs: x.bottom @ 0.5) to (side cs: h.left @ 0.5);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\StrCut\expandafter\sidecs@expandedarg\expandafter{\string@}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to solve the problem.

1. Since you're under `\fullexpandarg` you can simply do

   ```
   \StrCut{\sidecs@expandedarg}{\string @}{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{\sidecs@pos}
   ```
2. If not under `\fullexpandarg`, you can use a string of `\expandafter`

   ```
   \@xp\StrCut\@xp{\@xp\sidecs@expandedarg\@xp}\@xp{\string @}{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{\sidecs@pos}
   ```

   (where I use `\@xp` for `\expandafter`, that's available if you load `amsmath`)
3. Alternatively, the `\lowercase` trick:

   ```
   \begingroup\lccode`?=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup
     \StrCut{\sidecs@expandedarg}{?}{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{\sidecs@pos}%
   }
   ```

   which exploits the fact that `\lowercase` doesn't change category code.

Similarly for the `\StrCount` line:

```
\StrCount{\sidecs@expandedarg}{\string @}[\sidecs@numberofats]
```

or

```
\@xp\StrCount\@xp{\@xp\sidecs@expandedarg\@xp}\@xp{\string @}[\sidecs@numberofats]
```

or

```
\begingroup\lccode`?=`@ \lowercase{\endgroup
  \StrCount{\sidecs@expandedarg}{?}[\sidecs@numberofats]%
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Per comment by user egreg, one possible approach is to use `\string` on @ in two places in the code for "side cs". This turns it (at execution time) into an "@" with the catcode "other", which is what XString is looking for in this case.

Add the following line at or near the beginning of the code:

```
\let\ea\expandafter
```

Replace the first `\StrCount` line with the following:

```
\ea\StrCount\ea{\ea\sidecs@expandedarg\ea}\ea{\string @}[\sidecs@numberofats]
```

Replace the first `\StrCut` line (in the conditional) with the following:

```
\ea\StrCut\ea{\ea\sidecs@expandedarg\ea}\ea{\string @}{\sidecs@partbeforeat}{\sidecs@pos}
```